# ANTLR4 in C# catches only one token

Tags: c#, antlr4, antlr4cs

g4 file:

```
grammar TestFlow;

options
{
    language=CSharp4;
    output=AST;
}

/*
 * Parser Rules
 */

compileUnit : LC | BC ;

/*
 * Lexer Rules
 */

BC  : '/*' .*? '*/' ;

LC  : '//' .*? [\r\n] ;
```

Code:

```
var input = "   /*aaa*/   ///   \n   ";

var stream = new AntlrInputStream(input);
ITokenSource lexer = new TestFlowLexer(stream);
ITokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
var parser = new TestFlowParser(tokens);
parser.BuildParseTree = true;
var tree = parser.compileUnit();
var n = tree.ChildCount;
var top = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    top.Add(tree.GetChild(i).GetText());
}
```

After running above code I get single string in `top`: `/*aaa*/`. The single-line comment isn't caught.

What's wrong?

Comment: Should your grammar not allow repetition around `LC | BC`?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, yes it should... that's why I'm asking this question, I'm not sure regarding the syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All parser/lexer generation errors & warnings are significant.  Both `options` statements are invalid in the current version of Antlr4.

The runtime errors detail the root problem: unrecognizable input characters, specifically, the grammar does not handle whitespace. Add a lexer rule to fix:

```
WS: [ \r\n\t] -> skip ;
```

While not necessarily a problem, it is good form to require the parser to process all input.  The lexer will generate an `EOF` token at the end of the source input.  Fix the main rule to require the `EOF`:

```
compileUnit : ( LC | BC ) EOF ;
```

The correct way to allow for repetition is to use a `*` or `+` operator:

```
compileUnit : ( LC | BC )+ EOF ;
```